# Github: how to only grant visibility to a single branch?

Tags: github, git-branch

We build a project for a client. This project is hosted on a private repo where each branch is assigned to a different client.

We would like to grant a given client the right to see what's on his branch, without seing everything on the repo.

Is that possible ? Other possible solution ?

Thxandregards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a "clean" method for what you're looking to do.

Depending on how you want to communicate things you could make use of the Slack integration and the branch by branch filtering concept that has been raised.

https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/441

I question why your projects are a branch per client and not repo, (maybe the private repo cost?). In any case, if there are subtle differences between client projects can the main source code be parameterized so if multiple clients see the same files they don't actually know anything about your other clients?